# Converting between extprim::u128::u128 and primitive u128 in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm working with an old Rust module that uses the [extprim](https://docs.rs/extprim/) crate to provide a [u128](https://docs.rs/extprim/1.6.0/extprim/u128/struct.u128.html) type.

I'm trying to use this with a newer crate that uses Rust's primitive [u128](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html) type (available since Rust 1.26).

What's an efficient way to convert back and forth between these two types?

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue or providing a pull request and remove that type in that crate completly ;)

Comment: Maybe `as_built_in`? (https://docs.rs/extprim/1.6.0/src/extprim/u128.rs.html#178)

Comment: @phimuemue that looks like a great option - I didn't find it in the public docs, I guess because it's only conditionally available?

Comment: @phimuemue look at my answer, it is even easier than that, thanks for the hint! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

When your rustc version is greater than [1.26.0](https://github.com/kennytm/extprim/blob/master/build.rs#L13-L15) the [From trait is implemented](https://docs.rs/extprim/1.6.0/src/extprim/u128.rs.html#1609) and you can use `into` respectively `from` easily.

For a lower version than that see below.

---

As a note: *"The most efficient way"* is very subjective.

I would use the `low64()` and `high64()` methods to generate a rust `u128`.

```
extern crate extprim; // 1.6.0

use extprim::u128;

fn main() {
    let number = u128::u128::from_parts(6_692_605_942, 14_083_847_773_837_265_618);
    println!("{:?}", number);

    // going forth    
    let real_number = u128::from(number.high64()) << 64 | u128::from(number.low64());
    println!("{:?}", number);
    assert_eq!(number.to_string(), real_number.to_string());

    // and back
    let old_number = u128::u128::from_parts((real_number >> 64) as u64, (real_number) as u64);
    assert_eq!(number, old_number);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=d2e44293b7deb2824a9ebe592494ce29))

Since you can't compare both directly, I used the `to_string()` function to convert them to a string and compare those.

Comment: You could convert the `extprim::u128` to a string and then parse a `u128` out of the string, that would be a way too, but not very efficient :D

Comment: yup, that's the implementation I wanted to avoid :)